# How to set DHCP Options Set via AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc

I'm struggling to create a DHCP Options Set via AWS SDK / CLI that has a **name-tag**

[image: AWS Console Dialog Create DHCP options set]

My current code:

```
const ec2: AWS.EC2 = new AWS.EC2();
const createDhcpOptionsResult: PromiseResult<AWS.EC2.CreateDhcpOptionsResult, AWS.AWSError> = await ec2
    .createDhcpOptions({
        DhcpConfigurations: [
            { Key: 'domain-name', Values: [`${hostedZoneName}.${region}.aws.cloud.***`] },
            { Key: 'domain-name-servers', Values: dhcpOptionValuesByRegion[region] }
        ]
    })
    .promise();
```

I already tried

```
{ Key: 'name-tag', Values: [hostedZoneName] }
```

but the result was:

```
2018-09-24T07:01:41.826Z    ae6baf79-bfc7-11e8-be28-255ebcbc3290
{
    "errorMessage": "Value (name-tag) for parameter name is invalid. Unknown DHCP option",
    "errorType": "InvalidParameterValue",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/ec2.js:50:35)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
        "Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"
    ]
}
```

Please let me know how to set a name for the Options Set via AWS SDK

Documentation:
[API_CreateDhcpOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDhcpOptions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
await ec2.createTags({ Resources: [dhcpOptionsId], Tags: [{ Key: 'Name', Value: hostedZoneName }] }).promise();
```